# (JavaScript ?) Display div with different content on choice?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to display a div when I click on a single link (which will change the way css style) with variable content (eg a sub-div with service1, service2, service3 ). This div will be displayed also propose several offers that will only display the div payment when one of these offers will be selected.

It's maybe hard to explain (i'm not english so sorry for really noob level), so maybe with this image you will "understand" a little bit more:

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/38/1442422045-fonctionnement.jpg

I confess to being a bit lost with JavaScript for this kind of thing. I know it's probably achievable, but how? :-(

Thank you for your help folks!

Comment: Sorry, the "Hello guys" are not copied. So hello guys, first! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the way with altering CSS with javascript, assuming you are not creating the variable content on the fly, have the divs css for display  set to none.

```
#divID {
   display = none; 
}
```

Then set an event listener on your link to change the display style to block.

```
document.getElementById("linkID").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("divID").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I created a crude representation of what you asked without much effects. But the fiddle I created completely functions as you intended. If you click buttons on div 1 the content of div 2 gets updated. If you click anything on div2 the information is displayed in div3. Here is the example: [Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/we8cr30k/)

```
window.function1 = function(){
 var edits = document.getElementById('2');
    edits.style.background="aliceblue";
}
//SAMPLE CODE TO EDIT ANY ELEMENT BY REFERRING BY ID. CALL SUCH FUNCTION ONCLICK
```

Please check the example to understand it fully.